# Crystal Report not filtering SQL records based on selection formula

Tags: visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports

unfortunately I'm not an expert of Crystal Report, so I'll post here my question hoping for any help about my issue.

I want to display inside my report the result of a filter on a SQL RecordSet; this RecordSet is looked up from an a single table, of which I want to show some fields of my SQL table, while the filter I want to apply is based on a field parameter (defined static) that I'm trying to set programmatically.

Here below I attached my code where I'm applying the record selection formula, I tried also hard-coding the value instead of passing it through a dropdown selection:

```
            ReportDocument RPT_Doc = new ReportDocument();

            RPT_Doc.Load(RPT_Path_Name, OpenReportMethod.OpenReportByDefault);
            ApplyConnInfos(ref RPT_Doc);

            RPT_Doc.SetParameterValue("data_riferimento", "20161001");

            RPT_Doc.RecordSelectionFormula = "{viaggi.data_part_pre} = '20161001'";
            crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = RPT_Doc;
```

In the first image attached you can find the field parameter definition, while second image is the record selection formula I defined inside my report:
[image: My field parameter]
[image: Record selection formula]

The report always shows all the records of my table (more than ten thousand rows), instead of displaying a filtered RecordSet. The odd thing is *Preview function from Visual Studio works like a charm*; it prompts the field value, once I confirm the value the viewer displays the report with the rows filtered as I expect..

What am I missing from report/C# program configuration to make the record selection work?

Thank you in advance for any suggestion you can give me :)

Leonardo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, finally we got the solution to our issue.

We found the CrystalReportViewer object used to display generated reports has 2 different properties, *SelectionFormula* and *ViewTimeSelectionFormula*; both has default value set to empty string.
Below I attached the picture of .Designer.cs file with the 2 properties valued:
[image: Designer.cs file]

We commented those 2 properties and the selection formulas and field parameters applied through code / report designer worked again.

Comment: oh man! I've been searching for this solution for several days already. This one works. Thanks